# How to enumerate installed metro applications (native API)

Tags: c++, winapi, microsoft-metro, windows-store

Is there some native Windows API to enumerate installed metro applicatons? 
I was able to find only examples which use .net [like this one](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Package-Manager-Inventory-ee821079). There is also [Package Query API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh446597(v=vs.85).aspx) which I am using in my application to get info about concrete application, but there is no way to enumerate applications with this API.

Comment: The sample you linked to targets the Windows Runtime, not .NET. It compiles to native code and consumes COM (or Windows Runtime) objects. See [How to get the IPackageManager object with C++ desktop app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a24ae39d-aa38-4ead-af92-160eac9ae96f/) for help on how to activate an `IPackageManager` type.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, but if I understood it right, it uses WRL which is COM inside and it is not acceptable in my case. Package Query API do not require COM, so I thought there should be a way to enumerate applications with similar API.

Comment: WRL is one way to access Windows Runtime types, without using C++/CX. It makes code accessing Windows Runtime types easier (and safer), but there is no requirement to use WRL or C++/CX to target the Windows Runtime. If COM is not acceptable, then there is very little you can do in your application. COM is virtually everywhere. This is a really odd requirement.